# how to synchronize two controls?

Tags: asp.net, controls

I have two exactly radio button lists in my page, top and bottom. If I select a radio button in the top list, I would like the bottom list make the same change. Is there any way I could achieve this synchronization?
My radio button lists are in a content page.

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblVerification1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                <asp:ListItem Value="V">Verified</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="NV">Not Verified</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Update:
I wrote following javascript function, but it doesn't work. The first alert return 34, a werid number, I am expecting 2. The second alert return undefined. Can anybody tell what I did is wrong?

```
function rblVerificationClicked(source, destination) {
        alert(source.length);
        var selectedValue;
        for (var x = 0; x < source.length; x++) {
            if (source[x].checked) {
                selectedValue = source[x].value;
                break;
            }
        }
        alert(selectedValue);
        for (var x = 0; x < destination.length; x++) {
            destination[x].checked = false;
        }

        for (var x = 0; x < destination.length; x++) {
            if (destination[x].value == selectedValue) {
                destination[x].checked = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

In page_load, I added

```
rblVerification.Attributes.Add("OnClick", string.Format("rblVerificationClicked('{0}', '{1}');", rblVerification.ClientID, rblVerification1.ClientID));
rblVerification1.Attributes.Add("OnClick", string.Format("rblVerificationClicked('{0}', '{1}');", rblVerification1.ClientID, rblVerification.ClientID));
```

Resolved:
I found what caused the problem.
asp:RadioButtonList render as input type=”radio” HTML elements.
So to get asp:RadioButtonList client id, call getElementsByTagName(“input”) which will return an array of radio buttons.

Comment: You could use javascript to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to do this via JavaScript. I created some example code below:

The html:

```
<div id="list1">
    <input id="item1" type="radio" name="list1"/>Item 1
    <input id="item2" type="radio" name="list1"/>Item 2
    <input id="item3" type="radio" name="list1"/>Item 3
<div>
<br/>
<div id="list2">
    <input id="item1" type="radio" name="list2"/>Item 1
    <input id="item2" type="radio" name="list2"/>Item 2
    <input id="item3" type="radio" name="list2"/>Item 3
<div>​
```

The JavaScript:

```
$("input[name=list1]:radio").bind("change", function(e) {

    var chk = $("div#list2")
        .children("input[id=" + $(this).attr("id") + "]");

    chk.attr("checked", true);

});
```

​I also created an [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2eZkJ/) for it so you can see it in action.

Comment: Sorry, I am kind of new to Jquery. But will this line $("input[name=list1]:radio") work for a control in content page?

Comment: It depends how you structure your html, this example is based on the html I created, you have to modify it so it fits in your html.